# Open sets separating points in a metric space?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I was solving my Real Analysis assignment on Basic Topology, and I had the following statement to prove

> Let (X, d) be metric space. Show that any two distinct points in X are separated by disjoint open sets.

At first, naively, I thought that we'd obviously have some positive distance (by definition of metric), say $d$ between the points, and then we can construct open balls around each of the points of radius, say $d/4$. And then we are essentially done if we can show that the balls are disjoint using the triangle inequality, which all metrics satisfy.

But, I realized that this argument might not work if we have X consisting of discrete isolated points. Then we don't have any open ball surrounding a point, and the above proof will fail. I am afraid that this will serve as a counterexample to the theorem I am required to prove, and I am skeptical that I am missing something obvious.

So, could someone help me out with this?

Thank you.

Comment: Your original argument is correct.  For any $r > 0$ and any $x$ in the space, the ball $\{ y : d(x,y) < r\}$ is, by definition, open (it is a basic open set).  Even if this set consists of only a single point, it is open.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Yes, I realized that now since $d(x,y)<r$ also includes it being 0, and then the point belongs to the ball. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original argument is completely correct. If $x \neq y$ then $d=d(x,y)>0$ and the triangle inequality shows that $B(x, \frac{d}{2})$ and $B(y, \frac{d}{2})$ are disjoint and open balls are by definition open in the metric topology, so we're done. We *always* have a ball if the radius is $>0$, even if it reduces to $\{x\}$ , as it can in the discrete metric. It doesn't change the fact that that ball is then open. In the discrete metric all subsets are open and point separation becomes trivial. But the proof works in any metric space.